# how to get the below output in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

```
select bmuid from areamaster
```

Returns

```
AU15BA-001
AU15BLA-03
AU15B-02
```

i want the data between '5' and '-', like

```
BA
BLA
B
```

My attempt

```
select @string=substring(BMUID,CHARINDEX('5',BMUID)+1,CHARINDEX('-',bmuid)) from BLOCKMASTER
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
declare @text varchar(1000)
set @text ='AU15BA-001' // put your test AU15BA-001, AU15BLA-03, AU15B-02

declare @start varchar(100)
set @start = '5'

declare @end varchar(100)
set @end = '-'

select @text text_to_search
, substring( LEFT(@text, charindex(@end, @text)-1), CHARINDEX(@start, @text) + len(@start), LEN(@text))   result
```